# How to define condition for spliting vertices on corner and non-corner vertices?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

I have an undirected graph with $n<100$ vertices. The graph is simple. The coordinates of all vertices are known and fixed $(x_i, y_i) \in \mathbf{Z}$, $i=1, 2,\ldots, n$, the set of edges is predefinded, they are line segments with the length $1$ unit. The degree of vertices can be $2$, $3$ or $4$.

On the sketch below vertices $4$ and $5$ have degree $3$, while the remaining vertices have degree $2$.

**Question.** How can to split the set of all vertices with the degree equals to $2$ into two sets? The first set should includes the corner vertices $\{1, 3, 6, 8\}$, and the second set should includes the non-corner vertices $\{2, 7, 9\}$.

**Edit.**

[image]

**My attempt.**
Let the vertex $i$ be the corner vertex if its degree is $2$ and two incident edges do not lie on the same line.

We can select the $i$ vertex with degree $2$ and compute the angle $\alpha$ between the two incident edges  $e_1$ and $e_2$, if $\alpha == 180$ then we can say that $i$-th vertex is the non-corner vertex, else it is the corner vertex.

Comment: Your question is not very clear : 
 - what is your definition of your graph? for n>8, do you still have only 2 vertices of degree 3, or more? how are define the edges?

 -You want to split them given the condition "corner/not corner" as per your title ? you don't refer to this anymore in the question. How do you define a corner?

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I added some details to the question. I am looking for the solution thought the graph theory.

Comment: So your definition of a corner vertex is very dependent on how you represent the graph. I think it might be a good idea to define the terms independent of representation, and possibly up to isomorphism.

Comment: The coordinates are constants.

Comment: What is a corner vertex, exactly?  Does it have to be  one of the vertices of the convex hull, or is it enough that the two incident edges don't lie on the same line?

Comment: Don't you mean **graphic** more than **graph theory** i.e a collection of vertices and connecting edges. 

You cannot solve this with "graph theory", the (absent) definition of a corner depends on the coordinates, which is not part of the graph. The graph theory aspect of your problem will give you different embedding (drawings) of the problem, you cannot define a corner.

Comment: also note that your attemp "that vertices belong to different sets if $x_i==x_j$ or $y_i==y_j$ is not well defined : in your example, 4 and 3 should be in the same set, and also should 4 and 8, but 3 and 8 share the same $x$ coordinates and hence should be in different set.

Comment: @saulspatz, you are right, two incident vertecies do not lie on the same line.

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues The OP says he wants to split the vertices of degree two, into two sets, so vertex $4$ doesn't come into play.

Comment: I don't understand, the $x_i==x_j$ or $y_i=y_j$ criterion.  Suppose we have a large number of vertices in a horizontal line.   I would expect that, except for the two on the ends, none would be classified as a corner.  And where is it given that all the edges are vertical or horizontal?  The problem needs to be stated precisely.  What embeddings in the plane are allowed?  What exactly is a corner?

Comment: @saulspatz. same, you can have identical argument with points {6,3} should be in same set; {7,3} as well, but {6,7} should be in different set. This is if you use the condition as an *if and only if*, if it is only a *if* condition, then you need one set for each point.

Comment: Another issue with the update problem : "edges are length 1 unit". this is not the case in your example : 4-5 cannot be distanced by one if 1-2 and 2-3 are

Comment: @thomaslesgourgues, you are right, i have updated the definition of the corner vertex and condition and vertex 9 was added on the sketch.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to calculate the angle. You look only at the coordinates of the neighbours. If both have the same x- or y-coordinate, it is a non-corner node. Else it is a corner node.